# Can a generic identity function infer tuple types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that effectively returns its argument, currently typed as:

```js
function h<T>(x: T): T {
  // Actually do some more things, then:
  return x;
}
```

When I try this typing in the playground, the generic type is inferred as I expect for the following:

```js
h(123); // T: 123
h('stringval'); // T: 'stringval'
```

But when I pass a tuple, it gives me a union array type:

```js
h(['a', 2]); // T: (string|number)[]
```

Is there a way to write `h(x)`s type so that tuple arguments are inferred, or do I need to use a helper like:

```js
function tuple<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T {
    return args;
}

h(tuple('a', 2));
```

I would prefer not to force people to manually tag their tuple types, instead to infer them when possible.

Comment: for tuple literals just append `as const` to the argument

Comment: You can pass your arguments as `h(['a', 2] as const)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I pass a tuple, it gives me a union array type:
>
> ```js
> h(['a', 2]); // T: (string|number)[]
> ```

You write "when I pass a tuple", but you are *not* passing a tuple. You are passing an array.

> Is there a way to write `h(x)`s type so that tuple arguments are inferred

TypeScript will never infer a tuple type from an array literal. Tuples are a particular way of *using* arrays. TypeScript cannot read your mind, it cannot possibly know how you intend to use that array, so tuples *always* need to be explicitly typed.

The only way for your identity function to return a tuple is by passing it a tuple. When you are passing it an array literal, you are not passing a tuple, you are passing an array.

If you actually pass a tuple, your identity function works just fine:

```js
const thisIsAnArray                  = ['a', 2]; // inferred as (string | number)[]
const thisIsATuple: [string, number] = ['a', 2];
const thisIsAlsoATuple               = ['a', 2] as const;

h(thisIsAnArray);    // T: (string | number)[]
h(thisIsATuple);     // T: [string, number]
h(thisIsAlsaATuple); // T: readonly ['a', 2]
```

Note that nothing of this has anything to do with your function. Your function is working perfectly fine: it is returning *exactly* what is passed in, and its return type is *exactly* the type of the parameter.

In your test, you were *never* passing in a tuple in the first place, and thus you weren't getting a tuple out. You were getting out exactly what you were passing in: an array.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that worked for me:

```
function h<T extends any[] | []>(x: T): T;

h([1, 2, "hello"]); // => [number, number, string]
```